# Android create new Activity on Top despite "singleTop"

Tags: android, android-activity

I have got a Activity with

```
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

How can i manipulate an Intent in order to create a new Activity on Top. 
Cause in an exceptional case I need a new Activity.

Or is it impossible?

Comment: I can´t believe that nobody ever had this problem bevore....

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `singleTop` flag in the manifest and instead add it as a flag in your intents where you need them, using:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Then in the case where you do not need to use `singleTop`, do not set this flag.

Comment: The Problem is, that the Activity gets Intents from the Search Interface. And I dont´t know how to manipulate them.
The best would be if there would be an other way.

Comment: You'd need to somehow intercept the `Intent` after the manifest properties are applied. Unfortunately, I have no idea if it's possible. If this goes 2 days without an answer, I'll put a bounty on this question for you since I'm quite curious if this can be achieved.